# Blender Bones don't effect mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

It's my first time rigging something and it just won't work. I made the mesh, joined all objects together and cleaned the mesh up. I made a standard human rig and parented it via automatic weights to my object. If I go to the pose mode tab and rotate the bones, nothing happens. I also put a link to the Blendfile here, if you want to look into it. Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Blendfile: https://workupload.com/file/krJRfGdJ

Comment: Hi. Please expand on "it just won't work". What won't work? Where in the process does it go wrong vs what you were expecting?

Comment: [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post a link to a file](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)